# Why do SVG filters on GIFs cause serious flickering unless I layer a duplicate GIF underneath?

Tags: svg, gif, svg-filters

### [Codepen Link to Example/Test Case](http://codepen.io/rjreed/pen/oFetC)

*(Use the buttons to experiment with the example in the link abover - it's pretty self-explanatory)*

If I apply an SVG filter to a GIF image (either inside the SVG or externally using CSS/inline) the filtered image will flicker - which is understandable given how intensive dynamically applying a filter to a GIF is.

However, if I layer a duplicate gif directly underneath the first one, the flickering stops and the filtered GIF renders pretty well.

Exmple layering (using SVG image tags, but either way):

```
<g id="gifs">
<image id="bottom" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/ywkWhm3.gif" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"></image>
<image id="top" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/ywkWhm3.gif" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" filter="url(#south)"></image>
</g>
```

Anyone know why?